# Scraping Instagram for contact email addresses

Tags: python, request, scrapy, instagram, instagram-api

I'm new to the stackoverflow community but working on a scraping project for instagram (i'm not super technical). I want to start with 10 or 20 targeted accounts and scrape their contact email off their "contact" button if it's there. Then look at all of their "recommend accounts" to follow associated and do the same thing. Basically, trying to automate and aggregate collecting targeted email addresses from the "Contact" button on Instagram accounts in my niche.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a code writing service, therefore I suggest you show us the work you have done and any *specific* questions/problems you encounter. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Maybe you could just request the code from the NSA (keyword "one-hop") and offer them to share your lists with them?

Comment: phines, did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

> I want to start with 10 or 20 targeted accounts and scrap their contact email off their "contact" button if it's there. Then look at all of their "recommend accounts" to follow associated and do the same thing. Basically, trying to automate and aggregate collecting targeted email addresses from the "Contact" button on Instagram accounts in my niche.

You're not the only one working on this... I recommend starting off by reading [Instagram's API documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/). You will not want to try to scraping Instagram, the website changes to frequently - IMO. You need to get API access. There are some hurdles to doing that, namely:

1. You need to build you application in [Sandbox Mode](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/) which means you only have access to a very limited view.
2. You need to demo your application in a video. This is required for submission.

> The video screencast must show the Instagram login experience of your app, proper credentials and the usage of every permission you are requesting. We will not approve submissions if you do not provide a clear and working screencast.

3. You have to submit an application, and they are strict.

Your application will need to address one of three use cases:

- *To help individuals share their own content with 3rd party apps*
- *To help brands and advertisers understand and manage their audience and
  digital media rights*
- *To help broadcasters and publishers discover
  content, get digital rights to media, and share media with proper
  attribution*

Good luck! DM me if you need more help. There is a feature in [influencer marketing analytics software](http://promoplanner.net), PromoPlanner that I use to find influencers.